# I cant increment value by 2 or more than 2

Tags: c#, for-loop

How do i increment a value by 2 instead of 1? when i run my code it will go from 1-10 by adding 1 but i want it to go 1-10 by adding 2

```
  for (int x=0;x<10;x++)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(x);
  }
```

Comment: if `x++` means `x = x + 1` then what do you need to do to increment by 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can do instead -

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10;) {  
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            x = x + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should be the solution for you.

```
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x += 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks bro helped alot i dont understand why people downvote my question im new to programming